# Find the Jordan canonical form of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I’m working on my linear algebra assignment and now struggling to solve this problem, say, on the complex field, find the Jordan canonical form of
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\quad &\quad &\quad & a_1\\ \quad & \quad & a_2 & \quad \\ \quad & \dots & \quad & \quad \\ a_n &\quad & \quad & \quad \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$
Usually I’ll work with characteristic polynomial in order to obtain the eigenvalues when being asked to find JCF. However in this problem, at least I believe, finding characteristic polynomial can be a really tough task. See $\lambda I- A$ does not have a friendly look and there is no way to get the determinant and find all the roots.

I do believe the problem is rather difficult and I really do not have any direction in my mind. I would be very appreciated if anyone could offer some help.

Answer (score 1):

I will just indicate a possible approach:

Take a look first at the case $n=2$. Then you have the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_1\\
a_2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$, you can find the JCF of this matrix by simply dividing by dividing the second column by $a_1$. Namely you have $P=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\  0 & a_1\end{pmatrix}$, and

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\  0 & a_1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_1\\
a_2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\  0 & a_1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\  a_1a_2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Now you can look at the case $n=3$ and use your knowledge of the case $n=2$ to solve this. The matrix is

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & a_1\\
0 & a_2 & 0\\
a_3& 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$

Its trace is $a_2$ so you know you want to move the central element to a diagonal position, and then we will have a $2\times 2$ Jordan block with $0$ diagonal. Necessarily it will involve $a_1$ and $a_3$ and you can show that the JCF of this matrix will be
$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0& a_1a_3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$

With some work you can show that the Jordan blocks will be $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\  a_ia_{n-i+1} & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for all $i$ with the first diagonal element $a_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ when $n$ is odd.

EDIT: If you're working over an algebraically closed field like $\mathbb{C}$ you can further simplify your Jordan blocks. Can you see what the answer should be then?

Comment: Yeah, I’m actually working on $\mathbb{C}$. A simple question: does the Jordan canonical form looks like $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1 \\ a_ia_{n-i+1}& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ over a field which is not algebraically closed? I think in my text book it consists of a diagonal filled with one number and some 1s on top of it.

Comment: @Scanners well, for a real matrix and a complex eigenvalue $\lambda = \alpha + i\beta$ the Jordan block is $\begin{pmatrix} \alpha &-\beta\\ \beta &\alpha\end{pmatrix}$. And for real eigenvalues they look as usual. I just left it in that way because it depends on the values $a_ia_{n-i+1}$. For the complex case it is easier.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is reducible into two-dimensional subspaces $e_i\leftrightarrow e_{n-i}$. By a permutation of the basis elements, $e_1\mapsto e_1$, $e_n\mapsto e_2$, etc.,  it takes the following form $$\begin{pmatrix}B_1&&\\&B_2&\\&&\ddots\end{pmatrix},\qquad B_1=\begin{pmatrix}0&a_1\\a_n&0\end{pmatrix},B_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&a_2\\a_{n-1}&0\end{pmatrix},\ldots$$

Hence the Jordan form consists of $2\times2$ blocks with eigenvalues $\pm\sqrt{a_ia_{n-i+1}}$, one for each $B_i$; except that when $n$ is odd, one of the blocks is $1\times1$ $[a_{(n+1)/2}]$.

Thus the Jordan matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}J_1&&\\&J_2&\\&&\ddots\end{pmatrix},\qquad J_i=\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{a_ia_{n-i+1}}&0\\0&-\sqrt{a_ia_{n-i+1}}\end{pmatrix}, J_{(n+1)/2}=a_{(n+1)/2}\ \textrm{if $n$ odd}$$

Edit: Of course, the Jordan form is not unique, the $J_i$ can be ordered differently. Also, if $a_i\ne0$ but $a_{n-i+1}=0$ (or the other way round), then the above $J_i$ should be replaced by $J_i=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\diag}{\mathrm{diag}}$
If $n = 2k\,(k \geq 1)$ is even, denote $b_i = a_{i}a_{2k - i + 1}, i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$. Let $c_1, \ldots, c_t$ be all distinct values of $b_1, \ldots, b_k$, and
$e_1, \ldots, e_t$ be their multiplicities so that $e_1 + \cdots + e_t = k$. If $0 \notin \{c_1, \ldots, c_t\}$, then it is easy to verify that $\lambda I - A$ is equivalent      to
\begin{equation*}
\diag(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{k \text{ terms}}, \underbrace{\lambda^2 - c_1, \ldots, \lambda^2 - c_1}_{e_1 \text{ terms}}, \ldots, 
\underbrace{\lambda^2 - c_t, \ldots, \lambda^2 - c_t}_{e_t \text{ terms}}).
\end{equation*}
If $0 \in \{c_1, \ldots, c_t\}$, without loss of generality, assume $c_1 = 0$, then let $f_1$ denote the number of terms such that $a_{i} = a_{2k - i + 1} = 0     $  so that
$e_1 - f_1$ is the number of terms such that one of $\{a_{i}, a_{2k - i + 1}\}$ is not zero and the remaining one is zero. Note $f_1$ may equal to $0$ or $e_1     $.
In this case, it can be shown that $\lambda I - A$ is equivalent to
\begin{equation*}
\diag(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{k - f_1 \text{ terms}}, \underbrace{\lambda, \ldots, \lambda}_{2f_1 \text{ terms}}, 
\underbrace{\lambda^2, \ldots, \lambda^2}_{e_1 - f_1 \text{ terms}}, \underbrace{\lambda^2 - c_2, \ldots, \lambda^2 - c_2}_{e_2 \text{ terms}}, \ldots, 
\underbrace{\lambda^2 - c_t, \ldots, \lambda^2 - c_t}_{e_t \text{ terms}}).
\end{equation*}

For each of the above two cases, it is straightforward to verify that the group of elementary divisors is
\begin{equation*}
\underbrace{\lambda \pm \sqrt{c_1}, \ldots, \lambda \pm \sqrt{c_1}}_{e_1 \text{ terms}}, \ldots, 
\underbrace{\lambda \pm \sqrt{c_t}, \ldots, \lambda \pm \sqrt{c_t}}_{e_t \text{ terms}}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore, the Jordan form of $A$ is
\begin{equation*}
\diag(\underbrace{\sqrt{c_1}, \ldots, \sqrt{c_1}}_{e_1 \text{ terms}},
\underbrace{-\sqrt{c_1}, \ldots, -\sqrt{c_1}}_{e_1 \text{ terms}},\ldots,
 \underbrace{\sqrt{c_t}, \ldots, \sqrt{c_t}}_{e_t \text{ terms}},
\underbrace{-\sqrt{c_t}, \ldots, -\sqrt{c_t}}_{e_t \text{ terms}}).
\end{equation*}

The odd $n$ case can be treated analogously.